# Оттянутый ScrollView

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-scrollview

У меня есть layout, в нем содержится ScrollView, в ScrollView содержится RelativeLayout и другие элементы.

Как сделать так, чтобы после прокручивания ScrollView максимально вверх происходила загрузка layout?

Comment: Поясните вот этот момент: "чтобы происходила загрузка layout".

Comment: чтобы когда я оттягиваю scrollview происходила загрузка layout, который я создал, вроде как-то можно через viewpager?

Comment: возможно `SwipeRefreshLayout` для такого пригодится

Answer (score 2):

Задача делится на части:

1. Присваиваем [слушатель прокрутки для `ScrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365539/3212712) (по ссылке говорят, что делать это надо в onStart() методе Activity

   ```
   scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onScrollChanged()
       {
           //для horizontalScrollView
           int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX();
           //для verticalScrollView
           int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY();
           //Тут чего-нить делаем, например изменяем разметку экрана.
       }
   });
   ```
2. Выясняем [общую высоту содержимого `ScrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989894/3212712) (делать это надо не раньше onResume() метода Activity, т.к. до этого высота `View` ещё не известна)

   ```
   int totalHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
   ```

и в приведённом выше коде скравниваем её с `scrollY`

3. Загружаем ещё к-л layout. Способов много:

(нужно поместить `ScrollView` в к-л контейнер, например `FrameLayout`)

1. Ранее загруженный layout делаем видимым (например сделав его высоту>0)
2. [загружаем](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336047/3212712) разметку в нужный контейнер.

   ```
   FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
   View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, item, false);
   item.addView(child);
   ```
3. добавляем фрагмент в разметку

(**НЕ** нужно поместить `ScrollView` в к-л контейнер, например `FrameLayout`)

4. Переходим в другую `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого используется android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout. Надо не забыть подключить эту библиотеку.
В активити надо реализовать метод обработки этого события.

```
public class MyPage extends Activity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
private SwipeRefreshLayout layoutSwipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_page);

        layoutSwipe = ((layoutSwipe = ((SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutSwipe));

        layoutSwipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
     }

    /**
     * Обработчик обновления списка
     */
    public void onRefresh() {
        layoutSwipe.setRefreshing(true);
        // Выполняем свой код здесь
    }

}
```